# "peer not authenticated " error in Artifactory plugin - Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I am using Jenkins version 1.566 and Artifactory plugin version 2.2.2.

I am running artifactory 2.66 in its own jetty container. It was running as http but recently I changed it to https.

Now if I change the artifactory server url in Jenkins configuration from http to https and port 8443, I get the error:

```
"Error occurred while requesting version information: peer not authenticated"
```

If I go to https url and login using the same user name and password am successful. 
Why is this error happening and how to fix it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the certificate used for artifactory https valid? self-signed?

Comment: I used keytool to generate the keystore and set the keystore in New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSocketConnector of jetty.xml file. BTW, I retained http connection as is so that I could access artifactory through http and https.

Comment: Looks like the keystore used by Artifactory is not recognized by Jenkins? If you think that is the reason too, do you know how to make Jenkins recognize Artifactory keystore?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cause of this error is using a self signed certificate for the Artifactory server which is not recognized by the Jenkins JVM. This is a common issue when using self signed certificates.
To solve this issue you will need to import the self signed certificate into the truststore used by Jenkins (by the JRE used for running Jenkins), for example:

```
<JAVA_HOME>\bin\keytool -import -v -trustcacerts
-alias server-alias -file server.cer
-keystore /path/to/cacerts -keypass changeit
-storepass changeit
```

In this example:
`server.cer` is the self signed certificate you generated for Artifactory.
`cacerts` is the truststore used for Jenkins. By default you should find one inside your JRE - `<JRE_HOME>/lib/security/cacerts`. Notice this is not the same as the keystore used by Artifactory.
Notice the default keystore password is changeit. For more information take a look at the Oracle documentation for the [keytool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking time to answer my question. I do not have server.cer in JAVA_HOME to begin with. So I get this error "keytool error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: server.cer (No such file or directory)". How can I get a server.cer in there? Also, my keystore for artifactory does not have .jks extension. It is just 'keystore'

Comment: Most of the SslSocketConnector methods are depricated including setting the keystore. Am wondering if this is adding to the issue too.

Comment: Something not ok with the command.. I tried "sudo /usr/java/latest/bin/keytool -keystore keystore -import -alias jetty -file /automnt/unix_homes/artifactory/etc/jetty.crt -trustcacerts" and it imports to keystore(but does not solve my problem).. but with the command you provided, am getting an error "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect" and am very sure that my password is correct

Comment: please ignore my previous comment.. am still trying. I could not successfully edit my previous comment

Comment: Even I had the same issue... I have imported the certificates into java but still it is not resolved. Do I need to restart jenkins??

Comment: @Sumith08 yes you should restart. Please notice this answer is from 2014

Comment: @Dror, Thanks for your reply but.. It did not work for me. as I am try to send cucumber test reports on slack using Jenkin's cucumber slack notifier plugin.
I have raised a question on slack below is the link. Will you be able to help me please?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65628109/sending-cucumber-report-on-slack-from-jenkins