# jenkins and artifactory certificates

Tags: jenkins, ssl-certificate, artifactory

I need to run Jenkins over HTTPS.

I created the certificate and put it into the keystore. Then I launched Jenkins with the following options:

```
--httpsPort=8443 --httpsKeyStore=/etc/pki/java/cacerts --httpsKeyStorePassword=changeit
```

So far so good. But I had "peer not authenticated" error when deploying a file in the Artifactory. 
According to [a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920311/peer-not-authenticated-error-in-artifactory-plugin-jenkins) I added my artifactory certificate to the keystore.

Now I can deploy files on Artifactory but Jenkins picked up the wrong entry from the keystore (the one of Artifactory). And I have a wrong certificate associated with Jenkins.

I was not able to specify the alias which should be used by Jenkins.

According to [Jenkins docs](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) it's possible to run Jenkins with the following options:

```
--httpsPort=443 --httpsCertificate=path/to/cert --httpsPrivateKey=path/to/privatekey
```

But in this case I'm not able to use my Artifactory certificate.

How can I run Jenkins with both Jenkins and Artifactory certificates ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying different things I came to an idea to rename the alias of jenkins certificate.

The new alias is `jenkins`.

Strangely enough it solved my problem. For me it looks more like a hack than a solution. Put your real solution here and I'll accept it.