# Sending Cucumber report on slack from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, slack, slack-api

I am trying to send the cucumber reports which are jenerated on jenkins to slack using cucumber-slack-notifier plugin.
I have made all the configurations as per the document(It is a free style job).
https://plugins.jenkins.io/cucumber-slack-notifier/
My configuration are below

System Configuration

[image]

Job configuration

Send Cucumber Report to Slack
[image]

The cucumber reports are getting generated properly But I am getting below error when cucmber reports are send to slack.

```
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.verifyHostName(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:257)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:115)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.SSLProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLProtocolSocketFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:714)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:394)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:178)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:404)
    at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:330)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:96)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Message could not be posted
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:101)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:90)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.SlackClient.postToSlack(SlackClient.java:42)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.CucumberSlackService.sendCucumberReportToSlack(CucumberSlackService.java:34)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.slacknotifier.CucumberSlackBuildStepNotifier.perform(CucumberSlackBuildStepNotifier.java:57)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1907)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Send Cucumber Report to Slack' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please note the jenkins server runs behind proxy and from the jenkins server I am able to send the message using the curl command. The proxy setting are also added in the Advance tab of jenkin's manage plugin

Can I get some help please?

Comment: Any updates on this?